# Учет в рекомендательных системах аналогов

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Может кто-то подскажет в какую сторону вообще копать, как правильно сформулировать на русском/английском.
Делаю рекомендательную систему. Пусть есть покупатели и товары. Нужно рекомендовать товар покупателю. Одновременно происходит кластеризация пользователей. Крайне портят картину товары-аналоги. Для них в базе данных есть аннотация, что они относятся к одному типу. Если пользователь заинтересовался одним таким продуктом - он вряд ли заинтересуется другим того же типа. Хотя это не безусловно. Т.е. пользователь может теоретически заинтересоваться несколькими продуктами одного типа, даже может быть ситуация, что какие-то товары диктуют необходимость приобретения одновременно нескольких других товаров-аналогов. Т.е. полностью удалить информацию об отдельных товарах и работать с моделью пользователь-тип тоже как-то неправильно. Но и модель для пользователя-товар получается не корректной: выделяются кластеры пользователей, которые отличаются товарами, фактически взаимозаменяемыми и рекомендации, соответственно, неправильные. Я просмотрел много источников и везде описываются методы как найти схожие товары и их рекомендовать. Здесь некоторую схожесть надо как-то отфильтровать.

Comment: По-моему, вы запутались. Просто две ваши цитаты рядом. 1.  "выделяются кластеры....которые отличаются товарами, фактически взаимозаменяемыми и рекомендации, соответственно, неправильные." 2."какие-то товары диктуют необходимость приобретения одновременно нескольких других товаров-аналогов".  Для построения любой системы разъясните себе и нам - так рекомендация товаров-аналогов - это неправильное решение или есть таки необходимость одновременного использования товаров-аналогов?

Comment: @passant Чаще будут покупать один товар из группы аналогов, т.к. другие тогда не нужны, но это не безусловно: иногда покупают парами или товары из других групп (не из рассматриваемой группы аналогов) обуславливают наличие нескольких товаров-аналогов (зависимость, одно без другого не покупают). Плюс некоторые товары меняют название бренда, по сути это один товар, а получаются дополнительные кластеры. Проанализировать эти зависимости вручную сложно, ввиду количества данных. Хотелось бы чтобы система этому обучилась и почувствовала где есть зависимость, а где случайные предпочтения.

Comment: Есть аннотация группы товара, которая указывает его "похожесть", но не в том смысле, что покупателю понравится этот товар и он будет покупать из этой группы, а наоборот, он купит один товар и все. Но другой товар из группы он может купить из-за того что его требуют другие товары, которые он приобретает в качестве зависимостей. Или он может хотеть иметь резервный вариант, и для таких вариантов часто есть стабильные комбинации.

Comment: Ну, вы сами ответили - нет никакого запрета на покупку товара-аналога, например, по тому, что "он может хотеть иметь резервный вариант". А может - и по какой другой, нам не ведомой причине.  Но эта комбинация - не запрещена.  А далее - все стандартно.  И еще - вы ведь не ищете "похожие" товары, вы ищите те товары, которые покупает покупатель со схожим профилем. Если вы видете, что покупатели, купившие товар А часто покупают его аналог Б, то почему его не рекомендовать тому покупателю, который подобен по профилю? Ну хотите- выдавайте рекомендации "из той-же группы" в конце списка рекомендаций.

Comment: @passant Те алгоритмы, что я пробовал, мне ничего не дают для практики. Они выделяет группы "схожих" пользователей, указывая на отличия, которые погоды не делают. Не запрещено интересоваться аналогами, но обычно не нужно. Если делать кластеризацию только по типам, я тоже теряю важные зависимости. В группах товаров есть случайная составляющая, личные предпочтения покупателя, но здесь они меня не интересуют. Принадлежность кластеру вынужденная, а не то что ему нравится покупать. Мне нужно выявить существенные потребности не анализируя вручную 2 млн прольз. на полмлн товаров и их зависимости.